# Rails: How to only allow User to apply to job only once?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am creating a job board, and I don't want to allow the users the option to apply for the same job twice. How can I limit this?

**app/views/jobs/job.html.erb**

```
<% if applied_to_this_job? %>
    <div class="alert" role="alert">You have already applied to this job!</div>
<% else %>
    <%= link_to 'Apply', new_job_application_path(@job) %>
<% end %>
```

**app/helpers/jobs_helper.rb**

```
def applied_to_this_job?
    JobApplication.exists? user_id: current_user.id
end
```

Obviously this doesn't work because it checks if this user has applied to any job. How Can I check to see if the current user has applied to the job being viewed.

Also, how can I limit this at the controller level so that the user can't go to job_application/new and get to the form.

Comment: A before_action could be used in the controller to run a redirect_to to redirect the user if they've already applied, I'm confused about why your code doesn't work for you though. Doesn't it check to see if a job application exists for the user, and display an alert if they have? Isn't that what you are trying to do?

Comment: My code doesn't work because it checks all JobApplications, and if the user ID is present in any of them, it returns true, which wouldn't show the apply button for jobs that the user hasn't applied to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check and see if the JobApplication object is for this @job  try:

JobApplication.where( user_id: current_user.id, job_id: @job.id ).exists?

Comment: Thanks, This is exactly what I was looking for. I did't think to use @job in the helper.

Comment: I am still trying to figure out how to limit it in the controller as well.

Answer (score 4):

You would use a `before_filter` in the controller action.

```
class JobsController < ActionController::Base

  before_filter :has_applied?, only: [new, create]

  ....

  private

    def has_applied?
      if JobApplication.where(user_id: :current_user.id, job_id: params[:job_id]).any?
        redirect_to :index, alert: "You have already applied"
      end
    end

end
```

This would allow the user to visit `/jobs/new` and post the application to `/jobs/create` unless they have applied. If they have applied, they will be redirected to the index in the sample code.

Also as another answer has noted, it would be wise to pass in the job id as well. Updated sample code above to reflect.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working. The user is still able to get to "new" action and apply.

Comment: Updated answer to use an AREL search rather than a class method on `JobApplication`

Answer (score 1):

Although what you've accepted will work, I think it's somewhat of a surface-level fix.

You'll be much better using validators to determine if the user can actually create another job application. This will protect against any problems with the business logic in your "front-end" views

Here's how I'd handle it:

--

**Uniq**

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :job_application
end

#app/models/job_application.rb
class JobApplication < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   validates :user_id, uniquness: true
end
```

You may also wish to give your database a uniq index for your `user_id` column:

```
> $ rails g migration AddUniqueIndex

#config/db/add_unique_index.rb
class AddUniqueIndex < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
     add_index :job_applications, [:job_id, :user_id], unique: true
   end
end
```

This will give you a highly efficient DB-level uniqueness index - meaning that if you try and add any more applications than is permitted, it will either fail silently, or come back with an error.

---

**Controller**

The structure of the controller would allow you to be less stringent about the accessibility of the `job_application` functionality:

```
#app/views/jobs/job.html.erb
<% if current_user.has_applied?(params[:job_id]) %>
    <div class="alert" role="alert">You have already applied to this job!</div>
<% else %>
    <%= link_to 'Apply', new_job_application_path(@job) %>
<% end %>

#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :job_applications

   def has_applied?(job_id)
     job_applications.find job_id
   end
end
```